# CSS different in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ransack search and Foundation in my Rails app and locally css renders ok while the same app in production has a quirk: [image: elements too close together in conditions]

other things in the app are exactly the same.

I tested in Chrome and Safari - locally ok, production not ok.

Where can I start troubleshooting this?

UPDATE: I tried to run in production locally (assets:precompile) and it's the same as on the server... so how come asset compilation can change something?

Comment: Live url for this app ? and CSS code you use locally, can you post it here ?

Comment: If these inputs are created by HTML `<input>` elements, i.e. if they are inline(-block) elements, my best guess is the production HTML code has been probably minimized.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 - here: http://app.linkrecover.com/websites/139/backlinks - goto Backlinks and "Show search options", then "Add conditions". PS: I updated the question saying that this happens because of asset precompilation.

Comment: The first option above is correct displaying and the second is incorrect displaying ? If yes, i didnt see problem in my browser. The margin & alignment is fine

Comment: Did you click "Add Conditions" ?

Comment: @HashemQolami hmm but the upper one is then also minimized and it has spaces... why the difference.

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic I opened up the webpage bu I don't see any issues there. And I see that the HTML code is not minimized.

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic Oh I see, how do you append the elements by clicking on `Add Condition`? I see they're inline-block elements, any chance that you've removed the space/tab between HTML markup?

Comment: I tried to open the page in my Windows virtual machine (I'm on Mac) and check it from Chrome and IE and I see the problem in both...

Comment: @HashemQolami Ransack gem is doing this - it looks like the "Add Conditions" link has the HTML for the fieldset in data-fields and javascript is copying it to the DOM on click...

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic I'm not familiar with Ransack gem, but it seems that the space character between inline elements are removed. Alternatively, you could remove the space characters in the real DOM and use `margin` to create space between the elements.

Comment: Why is it working in development mode? It's the same code... with space character removed in the data-fields content. Ransack gem doesn't matter that much here... but it just offers search by all the fields on the model.

Answer (score 0):

One of the sites probably has a global css selector that set the margin or padding (can't really tell from your example).
Go to the production site and inspect one of the elements. You should see a difference in its computed style.

Comment: The funny thing is that I cannot figure out what makes a space on the upper fieldset... Here: http://imgur.com/KJW49VZ and http://imgur.com/4Hf4Xqo .. so it's not margin it seems... So no idea why there is space at all, would be nice to know to be able to figure out why there isn't on the lower one :) Also you can see it for yourself (upper comment)

Comment: I'm sorry but all of this is just guesswork. If you really want an answer by someone you'll need to post some code, because just looking at a picture doesn't really help.

Comment: I can do that, but there's a lot of it probably - and I didn't write it, it's from Ransack and Foundation... could you just look at it live maybe: http://app.linkrecover.com/websites/139/backlinks ?

Comment: And I would still like to know what's the reason for space and why cannot I see it with inspecting the elements, that really bothers me, but it's probably something obvious.